# Need to add header/footer and page numbers to PDFs

Tags: windows, pdf

We need to add header/footer information and page numbers to PDFs. I don't really want it to be free software. I'd like something where some thought has been given to the user experience. In general, I avoid Adobe software, so Acrobat is out.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you please [edit] your question and add some more details on the intended workflow? Do you want to add the header/footer stuff to already existing PDFs, or while generating them? In the latter case, what format is your input using? Are you converting existing documents, or do you need an editor included? What are your requirements concerning the GUI (if any; in case of conversion: GUI needed, or command-line/whatever preferred)?

Comment: Too bad, Adobe products often has some pretty advanced features. http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/add-headers-footers-pdfs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Foxit Phantom PDF](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/PDF_Editor/) offers several advanced PDF editing features. It is not free, but they offer a 30 day trial. Among the features listed on their website is:

> Easier insertion of headers, footers, and custom page numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PDFill PDF Tools](http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html):

- free
- Windows
- can add headers and footers to present information, such as date, time, page numbers, or the title of the document, in the top or bottom margins of a document.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many softwares for PDF editing, and for a paid one use:
1- [Wondershare PDF Editor](http://www.wondershare.com/pdf-editor/)
2- [Foxit Advanced PDF Editor](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/french/downloads/) is also another good choice.